# Rails server won't start after brew update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, mysql2

On my mac (sonoma), I installed wget: "brew install wget", which worked fine, but noticed it updated mysql as well. It went from 8.0.x to 8.3.0.

I then could no longer start my rails server locally. The error on startup:

```
 dlopen(/Users/jack/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/mysql2-0.5.4/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle, 0x0009): Library not loaded: /opt/homebrew/opt/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.22.dylib (LoadError)
  Referenced from: <E4E7E7D5-64FA-3F2B-8B01-B6F82F206D57> /Users/jack/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/mysql2-0.5.4/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
  Reason: tried: '/opt/homebrew/opt/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.22.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/opt/homebrew/opt/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.22.dylib' (no such file),
```

I noticed that there is a libmysqlclient.23.dylib file in there, not the 22. I did try reinstalling the gem to no avail. How to fix?

Thx.

Comment: I mean an install won't link against a shared lib that doesn't exist, are you sure you uninstalled and reinstalled the gem in question?

Comment: I did uninstall all versions of that gem and then reinstalled. I understand the core error, but I don't understand why it's happening, why is it missing? Or why would it be referencing something that's missing?

Comment: When you uninstall are you sure you're using THAT (rbenv's) version of `gem`? Perhaps you're uninstalling the wrong thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I finally found this article, which solved my problem. Note that the issue  was the inability to install the mysql2 gem properly. I had tried different ways to install it from different articles, to no avail. This is the one that worked.

https://prabinpoudel.com.np/notes/error-while-installing-mysql2-in-m1-mac/

Careful with cut-n-pasting the cmd from the article (the big long one to install the gem). I recommend just creating a shell script and typing it in to do the install since it's easy to have typos.